# Multiple lengths for substring?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, substring

Can a substring have mutiple arguments? I am pulling a substring from a drop down list into my database for records, the string is between 6 and 8 numbers, is it possible to pass more than one argument to make this work?

Sample data:

DropDownList

```
123456 | Name 
1234567 | Name 
12345678 | Name 

dt = ExecuteStoredProcedure(SqlConnection, "InsertData", "@name", ddlE_VN.SelectedValue.Substring(0, 6))
```

Comment: Could you show some example data?

Comment: This sounds like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with regular expressions could you elaborate?

Comment: Regular expressions let you identify *patterns* in text instead of chunks; it allows you to extract a string from another string as long as the pattern is followed.  Check out this site for details: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the data you show, this should work :

```
ddlE_VN.SelectedValue.Substring(0, ddlE_VN.SelectedValue.IndexOf(' '))
```

We are starting our substring at index 0, which is the first character.  If the space is the sixth character, it will have an index of 5, so we will return the first 5 characters.  If the space is the eighth character, it will have an index of 7, so we will return the first 7 characters, etc.

Comment: I am getting an errorexception saying my length can't be set to zero, and the "xxx12345" isn't working? anysuggestions?

Comment: Does your text contain a space? the syntax is s.substring(startIndex, Length). You'll have to give better sample data. What are the possible values for ddlE_VN.SelectedValue, and what part of those values do you want to extract?

Comment: The values are above the number sequence is anywhere between 6 and 8, then a space, then a "|" character then another space and then names that are multiple varying lengths. I store only the number in my database so I need to pull only the number sequence out of the dropdownlist

Comment: I edited my answer again.  My string s was just an example.  if ddlE_VN.SelectedValue always starts with digits, then a space then other characters, then ddlE_VN.SelectedValue.Substring(0, ddlE_VN.SelectedValue.IndexOf(' ')) should work.

Answer (score 0):

Substring can take only a start parameter and return the substring till the end of the string.

If your substring is separated with spaces or some other character, you could calculate the index of the delimiter and use that in your substring.

Something like this:

```
string myString = "part1 part2 part3";

int firstSpace = myString.IndexOf(' ');
int secondSpace = myString.LastIndexOf(' ');

string part1 = myString.Substring(0, firstSpace).Trim();
string part2 = myString.Substring(firstSpace, secondSpace - firstSpace).Trim();
string part3 = myString.Substring(secondSpace).Trim();
```

Off course, you can also use regular expressions for this but since your sample data is not that complicated I personally prefer this code.